# Time Machine inside a virtual macOS installed through VirtualBox? I want to backup the virtual macOS, not the host macOS. Possible?

Tags: backup, time-machine, virtualization, virtualbox, vmware

And then I want to do something even more voodoo. I want to take this Time Machine backup (from a virtual macOS) and install it on a real MacBook. Feels like it is going to explode, but maybe not.

My goal is to set up my new macOS environment (apps, configuration, etc) through VirtualBox inside my old MacBook and take a backup of the virtual macOS (not the host one running on my MacBook), then 2 months from now, when my new MacBook arrives, I'll simply copy one of these backups to my new MacBook and I'm ready to go!

Comment: You just need to backup the vbox file and the vdi (hard disk image).  If you need to restore, simply add the machine back into the VBox management console. If you must use TM, you’ll need to attach the USB device via VBox.  It’s not hard, but it isn’t efficient, either.  Use the first solution I described

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. There's really nothing special to it.

When you open up macOS inside the virtual machine, go to the "Devices" menu in VirtualBox, then "USB Devices" and select your Time Machine extern hard drive to get it mounted inside the virtual machine.

From there macOS inside the virtual host should recognize the disk and allow you to setup Time Machine backups as usual.

When your new MacBook arrives, just connect the external USB hard drive to the new computer, and let it restore from that during initial setup.

Note: Double-check that you have setup your VirtualBox for the highest possible speed USB. Older versions default to USB 1.1, which will mean much slower backups.